# Yasnippets for active web-mode engine

Tags: yasnippet, web-mode

Say I have a snippets folder:

```
snippets/web-mode/
├── django
│   ├── else
│   ├── for
│   └── if
└── erb
    ├── else
    ├── for
    └── if
```

Both engines have different syntax (`{% %}` and `{{ }}` vs `<% %>` and `<%= %>`).

How do I load yasnippets of a certain web-mode engine when it's activated?

---

**Versions:**

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-07-05
Spacemacs v.0.300.0 (develop, commit b00767cd6ec718df969bb1b7f713e5030ecf3c3e)

web-mode           20190301.1700
yasnippet          20181015.1212
```

Comment: How is the web-mode engine identified? Is it identified by the file name extension, such as `.djhtml` or `.rhtml`?

Comment: ERB (Embedded Ruby) usually has `.erb.html` but Django uses plain `.html` files.

Comment: It would be nice if you could you test [my solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48813/2370) and report whether it works for you.

Comment: Please add your Emacs version (`M-x emacs-version`), your web-mode version and your yas-version. You find your web-mode version and your yas-version in `M-x package-list-packages`.

Comment: @Tobias - versions added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right place to use `yas-activate-extra-mode` is `web-mode-on-engine-setted` since that function also sets the engine specific snippets of `web-mode`.

Pityingly there is no hook so we have to add an advice.
You can put the following into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

After loading that init file (e.g., at emacs-restart) your engine-dependent yas-directory structure works.

```el
(require 'web-mode)
(defcustom my-web-yas-mode-alist
  '(("erb" . erb)
    ("django" . django))
  ""
  :group 'web-mode
  :type '(repeat (cons
                  :tag "Map engine name to mode"
                  (string :tag "Engine Name")
                  (symbol :tag "Mode"))))

(defun my-web-setup-yas ()
  "Setup yas according to `web-mode-engine`."
  (require 'yasnippet)
  (let ((extra-mode (cdr (assoc-string web-mode-engine my-web-yas-mode-alist))))
    (when extra-mode
      (yas-activate-extra-mode extra-mode))))

(advice-add 'web-mode-on-engine-setted :after #'my-web-setup-yas)
```

<strike>Note that you should use the [web-mode as yas-parent](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-organization.html#org7468fa9) in each of your derived yasnippet modes (also those that do not exist as real major modes).</strike>
[Correction:](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48332/yasnippets-for-active-web-mode-engine/48813?noredirect=1#comment75691_48813) The snippets for `web-mode` are activated anyway since that is the  major-mode of the buffer.

Note: If you want to keep your directory structure you must consider following items:

- Use `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode` as one of the root-directories.

  - You can do that with the following code:

  ```
  (eval-after-load 'yasnippet
    '(let ((dir "~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode"))
        (add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs dir)
        (yas-load-directory dir)))
  ```
- You cannot load snippets directly from the directory `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode`.

  - Otherwise the snippets in all sub-directories are also interpreted as snippets of `web-mode`.
  - You can avoid loading snippets from `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode` by putting a file `.yas-skip` in there.
  - If you have snippets for web-mode in `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode` you could use another directory, e.g., `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode-engines` for collecting the extra modes `erb` and `django` in that case you must adapt the Elisp code here and the location for `.yas-skip` to that new directory. Actually, you do not even need `.yas-skip` anymore since there is no mode named `web-mode-engines` that could be loaded.

If you do not like that hassle of the previous steps you need to move `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode/erb` and `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode/django` to `~/.emacs.d/snippets/` and afterwards reload the snippet directory `~/.emacs.d/snippets/`.

---

Test conditions:

Running `emacs -Q`, version `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2018-05-29`

Via `package` library installed relevant packages:

- [`yasnippets-snippets`](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets) version 20190316.1019
- [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) version 20180101.1211
- [`web-mode`](http://web-mode.org/) version 20190301.1700

Reconstruction:

- Start Emacs with `emacs -Q`
- Run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-initialize`
- Put the following snippets into their places:

File `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode/erb/if`:

```
  # -*- mode: snippet -*-
  # name: if statement
  # key: if
  # --
  <% if $1 %>
    $2
  <% end %>
```

File `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode/erb/unless`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: unless statement
# key: unless
# --
<% unless $1 %>
  $2
<% end %>
```

File `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode/django/if`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: if statement
# key: if
# --
{% if $1 %}
  $2
{% endif %}
```

File `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode/django/with`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: with statement
# key: with
# --
{% with $1 %}
  $2
{% endwith %}
```

- Put the above two Elisp source blocks into the `*scratch*` buffer and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` there.
- Run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `yas-global-mode`.
- Open the erb test file with the following content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <ul>
      <% @products.each do |p| %>
          <li><%=  @p.name %></li>

      </ul>
  </body>
</html>
<!--
     Local Variables:
     mode: web
     eval: (web-mode-set-engine "erb")
     End:
-->
```

- Test result:

  - The `YASnippet` menu now contains the submenus `erb,prog-mode,nxml-mode,html-mode`.
  - Inserting `if` and pressing TAB results into the expansion of the erb-if-statement.
  - The `erb` submenu contains the items `if statement` and `unless statement`.
- Open the django test file with the following content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>About {{ title }}</h1>
    <p>This Website was developed by {{ author }}.</p>
    <p>Now using the Django's Template Engine.</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">Return to the homepage</a>.</p>

    </body>
</html>
<!--
     Local Variables:
     mode: web
     eval: (web-mode-set-engine "django")
     End:
-->
```

- Test result:

  - The `YASnippet` menu now contains the submenus `django,prog-mode,nxml-mode,html-mode`.
  - The `django` submenu contains the items
  - Inserting `if` and pressing TAB results into the expansion of the django-if-statement.
  - The `erb` submenu contains the items `if statement` and `with statement`.

Comment: I've put a `.yas-parents` file containing the string `web-mode` in both `django` and `erb` folders, and put the code snippet in my init. They don't tab-complete, but only the `django` ones show up when I call `yas-insert-snippet` (in both engines, different projects). However, when I remove the code snippet, they all show up in `yas-insert-snippet`.

Comment: I am using Spacemacs btw

Comment: @RicharddeWit Note, that if the `web-mode-engine` is not recognized it must be set by `M-x web-mode-set-engine`. I will add a note in my answer how you can do that by file-local variables.

Comment: the engines are recognized and active

Comment: What does `M-: web-mode-engine` say for a file with `erb` engine and a file with `django` engine? Both engines cannot be active in one file, can they?

Comment: They both say either `erb` or `django` correctly.

Comment: @RicharddeWit for this solution to work, I think you need the snippet under `snippets/erb` and `snippet/django` folders, not `snippets/web-mode/erb` and `snippets/web-mode/django`.

Comment: @RicharddeWit See [npostavs comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48332/yasnippets-for-active-web-mode-engine/48813?noredirect=1#comment75688_48813). An alternative is to add the the directory `snippets/web-mode` to `yas-snippet-dirs`.

Comment: @npostavs Adding `web-mode` as parent of `erb` or `django` is not really necessary, is it? The snippets for `web-mode` are activated anyway because that is the major mode of the buffer, are they not?

Comment: "The snippets for `web-mode` are activated anyway because that is the major mode" - yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Tobias - After including the `eval-after-load` snippet, I get the snippets from both engines in every `web-mode` engine (like `blade`)

Comment: @RicharddeWit It works for me. When I find some time I will add my test conditions. Note, that the snippets can be influenced by other packages (e.g., `yasnippet-snippets`).

Comment: @RicharddeWit If you do not want all the erb and django snippets in the web-mode menu you must put `.yas-skip` into the `~/.emacs.d/snippets/web-mode` folder. I added that and the test conditions in the answer.

Comment: @Tobias - **moving the snippets to a `web-mode-engines` folder** (and pointing the elisp code there) fixed the issue! I now have the `erb` snippets in an `erb` engine file and the `django` snippets in a `django` engine file :) Thanks for the effort and I'll gladly reward you the bounty. Now if you could perhaps edit your answer to preferentially put the snippets in their own `web-mode-engines` folder, that would be great.

Comment: @RicharddeWit I am happy that your problem could be solved. Note, that even if you put the engine extra modes into the folder `web-mode-engines` it is advantigeous to add a `.yas-skip` file there. That avoids that the subdirectories of that folder are read twice. I will edit the answer "to preferentially put the snippets in their own web-mode-engines folder" when I have some spare time.